# get FragmentTransaction which handles my fragment instance

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-fragments

I know I can start an FragmentTransaction to handle fragment like following way:

```
FragmentManager fragMgr = getHaloFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragTrans = fragMgr.beginTransaction();

MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
fragTrans.replace(R.id.content, fragment, "myTag");
```

I can also remove above `myFragment` by :

```
fragTrans.remove(myFragment); //Note, here I use the same 'fragTrans'
```

**But if I create a new** `FragmentTransaction` and remove `myFragment`:

```
FragmentManager fragMgr2 = getHaloFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragTrans2 = fragMgr.beginTransaction();

fragTrans2.remove(myFragment); //It won't remove myFragment, because it is another transaction
```

The above new created FragmentTransaction `fragTrans2` will **NOT** remove `myFragment`.

**My question is,** if I get `myFragment` somewhere without any reference of the original `fragTrans` , **how can I get** the `FragmentTransaction` (which handles `myFragment`) from `myFragment`, so that I can then remove `myFragment` by using the original(1st) `FragmentTransaction` ?

Answer (score 1):

Do you call .commit() after remove() ?